# Solving for angles of an n-gon with n-1 congruent sides, and one unequal side

Tags: geometry

Here are the rules of the problem I am trying to solve:

All side lengths are given, and all sides but one are congruent. The shape is always convex, and not self-intersecting; angles between any of the congruent sides will be the same, and the angles between the unequal side and an adjacent congruent side will be the same. The length of the unequal side cannot be more than the sum of the lengths of all other sides.
(The unequal side may actually be congruent to all the others, but the solutions must still work even when it is not.)

My goal is to find the measure of every angle.
I tried making the problem simpler to start, by tackling it in its simplest forms: an isosceles triangle, and a 3-sides equal trapezoid.

For an isosceles triangle, the equation to find the angle between the unequal side and one adjacent congruent side is $$\alpha=\arccos\left(\frac{a}{2b}\right)$$ where $\alpha$ is the measure of the angle, $a$ is the unequal side length, and $b$ is the length of a congruent side. The measure of the other angle can be found from this, with $\beta=180-2\alpha$ .

The formulas for a quadrilateral (always a trapezoid) are $$\alpha=\arccos\left(\frac{a-b}{2b}\right)\\\beta=180-\alpha$$

I found both formulas for $\alpha$ by replacing all of the equivalent variables and simplifying cosine laws. I don't know how to extend this beyond a trapezoidal shape, let alone come up with a formula that works for any n-gon that follows the rules set above, so I am looking for help.

Comment: I would start by picturing your polygon inscribed in a circle of (unknown at the moment) radius $R$ with a chord $B$ of length $b$ and $n-1$ consecutive chords of length $a$ joining the ends of $B$ on the circle. I haven't followed through to see if this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key observation is that the $n$ vertices of this polygon all lie on a circle. Once you have this, setting up the equations is fairly easy. Say the congruent sides of the polygon have length $1$, the other side length $d$, and let the radius of the polygon's circumcircle be $r$. Each side of length $1$ subtends an angle of $2\sin^{-1} \frac{1}{2r}$; the other side subtends an angle of $2\sin^{-1} \frac{d}{2r}$. Adding all these up (and dividing by $2$) we get
$$(n-1)\sin^{-1} \frac{1}{2r} + \sin^{-1} \frac{d}{2r} = \pi$$

The idea is to solve this for $r$, then find the angles.

For small $n$, this is solvable analytically, but in general you'll need to use a numerical method (eg Newton's method).

---

For example, with $n=4$, we have
$$3\sin^{-1} \frac{1}{2r} + \sin^{-1} \frac{d}{2r} = \pi$$

Rearranging and using the fact that $\sin 3\theta = 3\sin \theta - 4\sin^3 \theta$, this becomes
$$\frac{3}{2r}-\frac{1}{r^3}=\frac{d}{2r}$$

which gives $r=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3-d}}$

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful to tackle this using complex numbers representing vectors in the complex plane.

Suppose the $n-1$ congruent sides have length $b$, the noncongruent side has length $a$, the angle between congruent sides is $\pi - \beta$, and the angle between congruent and noncongruent sides is $\pi - \alpha$.  If the vector for the first congruent side is represented by $b$, that for the $j$'th is $b \exp(i(j-1) \beta)$, $1 \ldots n-1$,
and the vector for the noncongruent side is $a \exp(i ((n-1) \beta + \alpha)$.
For the figure to close we need

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} b \exp(i(j-1) \beta) + a \exp(i((n-1) \beta + \alpha) = 0$$
But using the formula for the sum of a geometric progression,
$$  \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} b \exp(i(j-1) \beta) = b \frac{1 - \exp(i(n-1) \beta)}{1-\exp(i\beta)}$$
so we get
$$ a \exp(i\alpha) = b \frac{\exp(1--i(n-1) \beta)}{1-\exp(i\beta)}$$
and then, multiplying and dividing this by its complex conjugate,
$$a^2 = b^2 \frac{1 - \cos((n-1) \beta)}{1-\cos(\beta)}$$
and
$$ \exp(i(2\alpha + n \beta)) = 1 $$
Since we're going once around, we should have $2 \alpha + n \beta = 2 \pi$.

Comment: I won't lie, this is hard for me to follow. My familiarity with complex numbers is limited. The only formulas which I understand are the last three -- which actually did help me towards solving the problem: I can always know what *β* is now, given any number of sides and a value for *α*. I'm still not certain how to solve for *α* on its own, however. I am out of time for the moment, so I will have to examine this more later.